# Is there any difference because of the syntax in this basic example of polymorphism? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say I have a superclass `BigClass`, and the subclass `LittleClass` inheriting from it. BigClass has a method DoThing(), and LittleClass has an overriding DoThing() method with different functionality.

Does it make a difference in any way to instantiate the subclass like this:

```
BigClass myNewClass = new LittleClass();
```

or this:

```
LittleClass myNewClass = new LittleClass();
```

I can see why the first one would be more useful as you can declare a lot of different subclasses in one line ect, but other than that is there any difference?

Comment: @user2864740 C# has sealed methods which are the analogue of final methods in Java. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BigClass` reference has access only to `BigClass` functionality, regardless of where it's implemented (e.g., `BigClass` or `LittleClass`). In other words, if `LittleClass` has a method that isn't overriding something from `BigClass` you cannot call it with the `BigClass` reference.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime there's no difference (in the sense you mean it). Your `myNewClass` variable is pointing to an object of type `LittleClass` in both scenarios. Any methods you call on it will be executed in the derived class (`LittleClass`), if it overrides them explicitly. If it does not, they will be searched/called in the super class, if not in its super class and so on.

The difference is at compile time. If on the next line you try calling some method `method` defined by `LittleClass` only (but not by `BigClass`), this will not compile in the first scenario but will compile in the second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As far as `DoThing()` method goes there's no difference.

Now, let say `LittleClass` class has `DoEverything()` method that was not inherited, since it's not even present in superclass.

I such case, `myNewClass.DoEverything()` will be legal only in your 2nd case (with reference variable of `LittleClass()` type).

Answer (score 0):

First one is useful as you can have polymorphic behavior using base class handler. If you know that the Base Class handler will always have this Derived Class object only, Having Handler of either base class or derived class makes not much difference.

Another difference would be that Base class handler can't access Non Abstract Methods implemented in Derived Class.

Answer (score 0):

The difference only be in the first scenario

```
BigClass myNewClass = new LittleClass();
```

you can only use

> myNewclass

object to access methods belong to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

One example is Factory design pattern : 
In factory pattern , you would have a method that creates various subclasses depending of user need and return the type would be BigClass in this case.

Example :

```
class Factory {

  public BigClass getInstance(int type) { 

     switch(type) {
        case BMW:   return new LittleClass() ;

        case AUDI:  return new Child2() ;

        DEFAULT: return new BigClass();
     }
  }
}
```

To use this:

BigClass obj = factory.getInstance(AUDI);
   obj.getPerformanceIndicators();